# How to add columns to existing tabular environment?

Tags: tables

I am creating a response sheet that has tables and there is a section where 4 columns becomes 7 columns. how can I go about increasing the number of columns in the table so that I can continue with the table from question 18 onwards?

Attached is an image of the desired outcome. Any help will be appreciated. [image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{wrapfig} 
\usepackage{array} 
\usepackage{color} 
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{tikz,lipsum,lmodern}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox} 
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{multirow}

\usepackage{geometry}
 \geometry{
 a4paper,
 total={170mm,257mm},
 left=20mm,
 top=20mm,
 }


\begin{document}




\vspace{0.3cm}
\begin{center}


\textbf{Response sheet}

\end{center}


\begin{Form}
\def\arraystretch{2} 

\def\DefaultHeightofText{12pt} 
% Use the following line to create the fillable textbox for responses
% \mbox{\TextField[bordercolor=, name = four,width=13cm]{}}

\begin{tabular}{ |p{0.5cm}|p{0.5cm}|p{12cm}|p{1cm}|  }
\hline
\multicolumn{4}{|l|}{\mbox{\TextField[bordercolor=, name = Name,width=12cm]{Name:}}} \\
\hline
8 & a)  & \mbox{\TextField[bordercolor=,name = 8a,width=12cm, height = 0.6cm, 
multiline=true, maxlen = 50]{}} & 
\mbox{\TextField[bordercolor=,name = grade8a,width=0.5cm, height = 0.6cm, maxlen = 4]{} 
/1} \\
\hline
 & b)  & \mbox{\TextField[bordercolor=,name = 8b,width=12cm, height = 0.6cm, 
 multiline=true, maxlen = 50]{}} & 
\mbox{\TextField[bordercolor=,name = grade8b,width=0.5cm, height = 0.6cm, maxlen = 4]{} 
/1} \\
\hline
 & c)  & \mbox{\TextField[bordercolor=,name = 8c,width=12cm, height = 0.6cm, 
 multiline=true, maxlen = 50]{}} & 
\mbox{\TextField[bordercolor=,name = grade8c,width=0.5cm, height = 0.6cm, maxlen = 4]{} 
/1} \\
\hline
10 & a)  & \mbox{\TextField[bordercolor=,name = 8a,width=12cm, height = 0.6cm, 
multiline=true, maxlen = 50]{}} & 
\mbox{\TextField[bordercolor=,name = grade8a,width=0.5cm, height = 0.6cm, maxlen = 4]{} 
/1} \\
\hline
 & b)  & \mbox{\TextField[bordercolor=,name = 8b,width=12cm, height = 0.6cm, 
 multiline=true, maxlen = 50]{}} & 
\mbox{\TextField[bordercolor=,name = grade8b,width=0.5cm, height = 0.6cm, maxlen = 4]{} 
/1} \\
\hline
 11 & a)  & \mbox{\TextField[bordercolor=,name = 8c,width=12cm, height = 0.6cm, 
 multiline=true, maxlen = 50]{}} & 
\mbox{\TextField[bordercolor=,name = grade8c,width=0.5cm, height = 0.6cm, maxlen = 4]{} 
/1} \\
\hline
13 & a)  & \mbox{\TextField[bordercolor=,name = 8a,width=12cm, height = 0.6cm, 
multiline=true, maxlen = 50]{}} & 
\mbox{\TextField[bordercolor=,name = grade8a,width=0.5cm, height = 0.6cm, maxlen = 4]{} 
/1} \\
\hline
 & b)  & \mbox{\TextField[bordercolor=,name = 8b,width=12cm, height = 0.6cm, 
 multiline=true, maxlen = 50]{}} & 
\mbox{\TextField[bordercolor=,name = grade8b,width=0.5cm, height = 0.6cm, maxlen = 4]{} 
/1} \\
\hline
 & c)  & \mbox{\TextField[bordercolor=,name = 8c,width=12cm, height = 0.6cm, 
 multiline=true, maxlen = 50]{}} & 
\mbox{\TextField[bordercolor=,name = grade8c,width=0.5cm, height = 0.6cm, maxlen = 4]{} 
/1} \\
\hline
15 & a)  & \mbox{\TextField[bordercolor=,name = 8a,width=12cm, height = 0.6cm, 
multiline=true, maxlen = 50]{}} & 
\mbox{\TextField[bordercolor=,name = grade8a,width=0.5cm, height = 0.6cm, maxlen = 4]{} 
/1} \\
\hline
 & b)  & \mbox{\TextField[bordercolor=,name = 8b,width=12cm, height = 0.6cm, 
 multiline=true, maxlen = 50]{}} & 
\mbox{\TextField[bordercolor=,name = grade8b,width=0.5cm, height = 0.6cm, maxlen = 4]{} 
/1} \\
\hline

\end{tabular}
\end{Form}
```

Comment: Is possible to post the full `MWE`, i.e., from `\documentclass{...}...\end{document}`

Comment: @MadyYuvi I have updated my code and this is what i have so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the modified `MWE` below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{wrapfig} 
\usepackage{array} 
\usepackage{color} 
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{tikz,lipsum,lmodern}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox} 
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{makecell}%

\usepackage{geometry}
 \geometry{
 a4paper,
 total={170mm,257mm},
 left=20mm,
 top=20mm,
 }


\begin{document}




\vspace{0.3cm}
\begin{center}


\textbf{Response sheet}

\end{center}


\begin{Form}
\def\arraystretch{2} 

\def\DefaultHeightofText{12pt} 
% Use the following line to create the fillable textbox for responses
% \mbox{\TextField[bordercolor=, name = four,width=13cm]{}}

\begin{tabular}{ |c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\Xhline{0.5pt}
13 &a & & & & & &/1\\
\cline{2-8}
&b  & & & & & &/1\\
\cline{2-8}
&c  & & & & & &/1\\
\Xhline{0.5pt}
15 &a & & & & & &/1\\
\cline{2-8}
&b  & & & & & &/1\\
\Xhline{0.5pt}
18 & &Hospital &$r=distance$ from &\multicolumn{2}{c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{$d=depth$ of
sediments (m)}} &\multirow{2}{*}{$V_s30$ (m/s)} &\\
& &name &epicenter (km) &\multicolumn{1}{c}{} & & &\\
\cline{2-8}
 & &USC &(a) &\multicolumn{2}{c|}{(b)} &(c) &/3 \\
 & &University & &\multicolumn{1}{c}{} & & &\\
 & &Hopsital & &\multicolumn{1}{c}{} & & &\\
\hline
19 & &Hospital &$\mu$ &PGA (g) &PGA (cm/s$^{2}$) &IMM &\\
\hline
& &USC &(a) &(b) &(c) &(d) &/4\\
& &University & & & & &\\
& &Hospital & & & & &\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{Form}

\end{document}
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for the help, however, questions 13 and 15 shouldn't have the column division.